# Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll

Tags: wpf

I downloaded the library "DynamicDataDisplay"(its source code). Some projects require file Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll. 
Where can i get it?
I searched it, but it doesn't exist on my hdd.

Comment: iv'e downloaded it recently and i don't see any project which references Microsoft.Windows.Design

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll should be installed in the GAC if you have Visual Studio etc..

Have a look at `C:\Windows\assembly` to see if it's there

Comment: No, that directory doesn't contain this file. Also,i reinstall Windows, but problem with this file doesnt leave