# Missed dll-file(Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I downloaded the library "DynamicDataDisplay"(its source code). Some projects require file Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll. Where can i get it? I searched it, but it doesn't exist on my hdd.
Directory C:\Windows\assembly doesn't contain this file.
 Also,i reinstalled Windows, but problem with this file doesnt leave

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834371/microsoft-windows-design-dll). It is not recommended to recreate exactly the same question in short amount of time, especially without providing any useeful feedback on previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the following topics:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/89339268-57c6-4f23-9dd9-c1022a1ea7b4

http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/274937

Comment: I saw it links. Can you explaine me, what exactly i should do? I can't solve this problem

Comment: I've downloaded the DynamicDataDisplay and can't see the reference to Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll. Anyway, the dll goes with the Visual Studio and can be found in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.

Also, try removing the reference - it may compile without it.

Comment: I've tried to do it. Did you download DynamicDataDisplay Sources?
For instance, in the projects of solution "DynamicDataDisplay" called DynamicDataMarkersDesign or DynamicDataDesign requires this dll. I have 3 warnings in the references of this projects

Comment: Also, directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies doesn't contain only one file - Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll

Comment: Project doesn't compile without this files

Comment: You can always download precompiled code :)
As I understand it, the design dll brings support for visual studio designer mode and doesn't affect application runtime.

Comment: I want to learn sources of D3, so i should solve this problem